# How can I make login and sign up function using Spree API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-auth-devise

I am pretty new to Spree and I've been trying to integrate react with it by having backend as spree and frontend as react. I've tried to figure out on how to I can let users login to the store using Spree API, but I couldn't find any API related to it.

I've looked into this https://guides.spreecommerce.org/api/v2/, but they don't seem to have login and signup API.

I would appreciate your help, I've been trying so hard to figure this out for the past few days